# Which HTML 5 tag attributes can contain URL?

Tags: html, dom, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to figure out which HTML 5 tags contains attributes that can contains a URL.

Looks like most of them (if not all) are the `src`, `srcset` and `href` attributes of the html elements.

So far I listed some of the most used ones:

```
- Tag: a       - Attribute: href
- Tag: img     - Attribute: src
- Tag: img     - Attribute: srcset
- Tag: base    - Attribute: href
- Tag: embed   - Attribute: src
- Tag: link    - Attribute: href
- Tag: script  - Attribute: src
```

PS: I'm not interested in `data-*` custom attributes

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Because, with custom `data-*` attributes, *any* element may contain an attribute that contains a URL.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/fullindex.html#attributes-table

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm interested only in HTML5 standard attributes elements (not including the custom `data-*` ones). Thank you

Comment: @Quentin thats what I'm looking for! As it mention what are the possible values for each attribute, like the `action` attribute of the `form` element: "Valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces". Thank you!